# After I installed Ubuntu on HDD and rebooting i into it, my PC can no longer find any OS

Tags: windows, xubuntu, kubuntu, reboot

So I started by installing xubuntu, it worked fine on my laptop accept that the network didn't work, I then tryed with Kubuntu and the same happens. After a while i tryed the original Ubuntu 15.10 but it would not install, though that is not mg issue ATM. After severely tryes I decided to use my main desktop PC and use Unetbootin to install it. So i tryed the option where you install the OS alongside Windows, after reboot and selecting the Unetbootin in the selection if windows or Unetbootin my PC restarts again but know it can't find any OS?

Anyone knows why? Or how I can restore my OS?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed did you install a bootloader?

Try rebooting into the liveUSB, and choose **Try ubuntu.**
Once you've done that, open a Terminal and type the following to install Boot-Repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair
```

After doing that, it should open Boot-Repair, Press Recommended Repair. Then, once its done, press OK, and reboot. 
See if that works.